# XmlSerializer InvalidOperationExc - known issue converting types

Tags: c#, xml-serialization, xsd.exe

I am using XmlSerializer against an XSD.EXE generated class.

```
XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(obj.GetType());
```

Throws up

> **InvalidOperationException** Unable to
>   generate a temporary class (result=1).
>   error CS0030: Cannot convert type
>   'itemOrderItemsItem[]' to
>   'itemOrderItemsItem' error CS0029:
>   Cannot implicitly convert type
>   'itemOrderItemsItem' to
>   'itemOrderItemsItem[]'

The [fix](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/asmxandxml/thread/e33305c3-b5f6-4922-8a3f-df202088d25a) (labeled `<!--fix...-->` below) says to add some silly element to my schema, but this isn't working.  This fix is five years old.  Is there a solution yet?

```
              <xs:sequence>
              <xs:element name="item" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                <xs:complexType>
                  <xs:sequence>
                    <xs:element name="model" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
                    <xs:element name="description" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
                    <xs:element name="material" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
                    <xs:element name="lot" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
                    <xs:element name="serial" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
                    <xs:element name="transferQty" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
                    <xs:element name="shipQty" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
                  </xs:sequence>
                </xs:complexType>
              </xs:element>     
            </xs:sequence>
       <xs:attribute name="tmp" type="xs:string" /><!--fix...-->
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have XML of the form

```
 <items>
    <item>
      <model>10</model>
      <description>Torque wrench</description>
      <material>100</material>
      <lot>3</lot>
      <serial></serial>
      <transferQty>1</transferQty>
      <shipQty></shipQty>
    </item>
    <item>
           //...
    </item>
    <item>
           //...
    </item>
  </items>
```

Xsd.exe will generate a xsd:

```
<xs:element name="items" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
              <xs:complexType>
                <xs:sequence>
                  <xs:element name="item" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                    <xs:complexType>
                      <xs:sequence>
                        <xs:element name="model" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
                        <xs:element name="description" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
                        <xs:element name="material" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
                        <xs:element name="lot" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
                        <xs:element name="serial" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
                        <xs:element name="transferQty" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
                        <xs:element name="shipQty" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
                      </xs:sequence>
                    </xs:complexType>
                  </xs:element>
                </xs:sequence>
              </xs:complexType>
            </xs:element>
```

Then

> xsd.exe "this.xsd" /c

Generates a class with two dimensional arrays (items[][]).  I only wanted a one dimensional array.  I changed the first line:

```
<xs:element name="items" minOccurs="0"><!--got rid of maxOccurs (which is what causes the issue)-->
```

Now it works. Guess the serializer just barfs on two dimensional arrays.  Luckily I dont need them.

Answer (score 3):

**This fixed it** for me, in  xsd file where child element had maxOccurs="unbounded" I added extra line after `</xs:sequence>`:

```
<xs:attribute name="tmp" type="xs:string" />
```

its a known problem in XmlSerializer Code Generation component: it cannot handle some cases of nested unbounded elements.  The Object Model it creates is not valid: user cannot use it to produce xml messages.

Unfortunately to fix this you have to edit your schema to make sure that all array-like constructs will be handled properly.
You would need to slightly modify all schema constructs that have the following:

```
<xs:sequence maxOccurs="unbounded">
  <xs:element ../>
<xs:sequence>
```

or

```
<xs:sequence>
  <xs:element maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
<xs:sequence>
```

**Have to be changed to (respectively)**

```
<xs:sequence maxOccurs="unbounded">
  <xs:element ../>
<xs:sequence>
<xs:attribute name="tmp" type="xs:string" /> <!--FIX LINE TO BE ADDED-->
```

or

```
<xs:sequence>
  <xs:element maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
<xs:sequence>
<xs:attribute name="tmp" type="xs:string" /> <!--FIX LINE TO BE ADDED-->
```

Comment: Is there a link to a bug report? This has been known since beginning of dot net it seems and we are at version 4, and the problem is still there